# Nuxt 2 on Azure App Services deployment : MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js, azure-appservice

I have a Nuxt 2 app and I have followed steps in here - https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/azure-portal/ to setup Azure deployment. I have also setup Github Actions for deployment. I see that the deployment on github goes through but the application refuses to start.

My `package.json` has this section for scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "node ./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
```

I see this in the logs

```
/home/LogFiles/2022_09_03_pl1sdlwk0008NU_default_docker.log  (https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_09_03_pl1sdlwk0008NU_default_docker.log)
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142920858Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142925458Z     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142941958Z     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142946858Z     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142950858Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142954758Z   requireStack: []
2022-09-03T08:48:10.142958558Z }
2022-09-03T08:48:10.172379715Z error Command failed with exit code 1.
2022-09-03T08:48:10.173393521Z info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.


/home/LogFiles/2022_09_03_pl1sdlwk0008NU_docker.log  (https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_09_03_pl1sdlwk0008NU_docker.log)
2022-09-03T08:42:26.147Z ERROR - Container myapp_0_446bf5b8 for site myapp has exited, failing site start
2022-09-03T08:42:26.187Z ERROR - Container myapp_0_446bf5b8 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-03T08:42:26.196Z INFO  - Stopping site myapp because it failed during startup.
2022-09-03T08:48:06.476Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-03T08:48:06.477Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name myapp_0_e36f2a54 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myapp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=myapp.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=475f8d8be78909ccab45ad7165366c8164ab3dcf6333cfcfe3ccd20b80150e8a -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e NODE_OPTIONS=--require /agents/node/build/src/Loader.js -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False appsvc/node:16-lts_20220309.1
2022-09-03T08:48:08.208Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container myapp_0_e36f2a54 for site myapp
2022-09-03T08:48:11.251Z ERROR - Container myapp_0_e36f2a54 for site myapp has exited, failing site start
2022-09-03T08:48:11.287Z ERROR - Container myapp_0_e36f2a54 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-03T08:48:11.296Z INFO  - Stopping site myapp because it failed during startup.

Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---
Starting Live Log Stream ---
```

Would you know what might be going on here ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does it work if you build it locally?

Comment: Also, do you have a [repro] for that one? Or a public Github repo?

Comment: Thank you for replying ! Unfortunately its a private git repo :( . I was able to yarn install and yarn dev locally. Also was able to change NODE_ENV to production and run yarn build and yarn start locally and that goes through as well. Is there anything else I can provide which might help ?

Comment: You may look into some Github issues but otherwise, I'm not sure how to debug it further unfortunately.

Comment: @kissu I tried manually deploying through azure cli using > "az webapp deploy --resource-group myapp_group --name myapp --type zip --src-path releases.zip --timeout 9000000 --verbose --clean true --debug" . This gives me a a 504 - https://pastebin.pl/view/6a05002e . Do you know if there is anything else I can try ?